# CPU load average spikes every hour with CPU 55% and memory 82% only

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, cpu-load

Our Digital Ocean droplet's CPU load average spikes every 1-1.5 hour. Here is the the performance graph for the past 24 hours:
[image]

[Here](https://pastebin.com/UeRSVBmi) are some MySQL error logs for 1.5 hours (one cycle) as well as syslog for 1.5 hours (one cycle).

Some folks commented that:

> Our mysql instance is being killed regularly by Linux’s OOM (out of memory) killer. You should review the load consumed by the resources running on the server. Based on experience it’s usually down to a greedy query that causes a resource contention and makes Linux sacrifice the most expensive process.

However, if you look at the [syslog](https://pastebin.com/3CCqp8Fi), it is because there were a bunch of **apache** child processes running which crashed mysql. These apache child processes killed the process! They run every 1-1.5 hours! We don't have any cron jobs.

Besides, if you look at the performance graph, even when the cpu load average (1 min) peaks at 20.71, the cpu hit 46.47% only and the memory hit 53%. The highest cpu and memory have never exceeded 57.5% and 88% respectively.

I found many related threads on Google but they don't seem make any sense in my case including using swap, limiting apache child processes, etc. For instance, limiting apache child processes is just fire fighting. We got to find out the crux of the problem which is why there are so many apache child processes running in the first place which only cropped up about 10 days ago.

Also, here is the [htop log](https://pastebin.com/vFVfRjmj) when the sites were momentarily down. Both cores shot up to 100% momentarily but the CPU stayed below 50%.

Any idea will be very much appreciated!!

Thanks a lot!

BR, Tom

Comment: Readers: Also posted on [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2446714).

Comment: hi @DougSmythies,

thanks for your comment.

first, no one from DO support replied to me even after i had opened two tickets. then i got some comments from the DO community but i still can't figure out why so many apache child processes were running and killing mysql. it's been almost two weeks since this problem first cropped up so i've become so desperate to get this fixed.

any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

br,
tom